# Form not redirecting correctly Wicket

Tags: forms, wicket

```
private void setDefaultResponsePageIfNecessary() {

    if(!continueToOriginalDestination()) {
        if(session.getRoles().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            setResponsePage(SearchForCapacity.class);
            System.out.println("Role for Admin:" + session.getRoles());
        } else if (session.getRoles().equals("ROLE_USER"));
            setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
            System.out.println("Role for User: " + session.getRoles());
    }
}
```

Hi all, this extract is from my login class which works fine except it wont redirect to the correct page. I can print the roles to the console so for admin it will print ROLE_ADMIM etc. The problem is no matter what the role it always navigates to the same page (HomePage), does anyone know why this is? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else if` statement is terminated by a `;` instead of opening a block with `{`.

```
private void setDefaultResponsePageIfNecessary() {

    if(!continueToOriginalDestination()) {
        if(session.getRoles().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            setResponsePage(SearchForCapacity.class);
            System.out.println("Role for Admin:" + session.getRoles());
        } else if (session.getRoles().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
            setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
            System.out.println("Role for User: " + session.getRoles());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also use `getRoles().contains()` instead of `getRoles().equals()`.